# Bootstrap Row starts up behind the margin

Tags: javascript, html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I am currently learning Bootstrap. I came across a piece of code where I was trying to create a bunch of rows to create a kind of table. But when I ran the code on the browser, the margins of the rows start of behind the screen. Look at the very simple piece of 'Hello World' code below in JS Fiddle.

```
<div class="row">Hello World!</div>
```

http://jsfiddle.net/x8y50sas/

Why is the text starting from behind the margins? An detailed explanation could help?

Comment: Please read this http://getbootstrap.com/css/

Comment: Rows must be placed within a .container (fixed-width) or .container-fluid (full-width) for proper alignment and padding.
Use rows to create horizontal groups of columns.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to include a cell inside the row:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <div class="col-xs-12">Hello World!</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

The reason for the offset is that rows in bootstrap have a negative margin. They should always contain a cell which adds additional padding.

More info in the docs: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#grid

Answer (score 1):

Because to be able to use the grid system you need to wrap your element inside class `container`. Read this article: http://getbootstrap.com/css/#overview-container

Example:

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="row">Hello World!</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 1):

You must enclose the block "row" in the block "container" as:

```
<div class="container">
  <div class="row">
    <!-- Example: 3 Cell -->
    <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
    <div class="col-lg-4">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```